# Bohr electron energy states problem - my solution feels like it is incorrect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

I am taking a quantum mechanics course for fun, and the book does not have solutions. The course is MIT 8.04 and the book is Mastering Quantum Mechanics. I am having a hard time figuring out if my answer to this question is correct. Could use some insight into why my final answer looks the way that it does.

#### Problem

Consider an electron in circular motion around a fixed (heavy) proton as a model for the hydrogen atom. Let $V = -\frac{e^2}{r}$ denote the potential energy of the electron and $F = \frac{e^2}{r^2}$ be the magnitude of the electrostatic force acting on the electron.

1. Find expressions for the kinetic energy $K$ of the electron and for the potential energy $V$ of the electron in terms of the total energy $E$ of the electron.
2. Assume that the magnitude $L$ of the electron's angular momentum is quantized and equal to $n\hbar$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Find the quantized values for the total energy $E_n$ and the associated orbit radii $r_n$.

Write your answers in terms of $n$, the rest energy $E_e = m_ec^2$ of the electron, the reduced Compton wavelength $\lambda = \frac{h}{m_ec}$, and the fine structure constant $\alpha = \frac{e^2}{hc}$.

---

#### My Solution

1. The total energy ( E ) is given by:

$E = K + V = \frac{mv^2}{2} - \frac{e^2}{r}$

$F = \frac{mv^2}{r} = \frac{e^2}{r^2} => v^2 = \frac{e^2}{mr}$

$E = -\frac{e^2}{2r}$

2. Substituting ( L = mvr ) and solving for ( r ):

$r = \frac{nh}{mc}$

3. More substitutions for $\alpha = \frac{e^2}{hc}$ and $E_e = m_ec^2$:

$E = -\frac{e^2mc}{2nh} \implies E = -\frac{\alpha mc^2}{2n} = -\frac{\alpha E_e}{2n}$

4. Here is where I get confused. I need to fit in $\lambda = \frac{h}{mc}$. I can do $\frac{mch}{mch}$ as a trick here:

$E = -\frac{\alpha h E_e mc}{2n h mc} = -\frac{\alpha hE_e}{2n\lambda mc}$

I'm not confident in this answer. Both $\lambda$ and $m_e$ are *very* small numbers. This leads me to believe this is a huge energy, which I don't think is correct. The book doesn't have solutions, and I can't find this problem (expressed in these terms) by Googling.

Maybe I'm misinterpreting the question. The wording could possibly be trying to express that $E = -\frac{\alpha E_e}{2n}$ is correct for the energy - but then I need to equate this to $\frac{-e^2}{2r}$, solve for $r$, and then that answer for the orbital radii should be express in terms of $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Going to leave this up for anyone hoping to find a solution:

leave energy as is, without trying to jam $\lambda$ into it:

$E = \frac{-\alpha E_e}{2n}$

Now take first answer $E_n = \frac{-e^2}{2r}$ and solve for $r$.

$r = \frac{e^2 n}{\alpha E_e}$

now unapply $\alpha$ and $E_e$:

$r = \frac{hcn}{E_e} => r = \frac{hcn}{mc^2}$

Finally $r = \frac{hn}{mc} = \lambda n$